# Nothing to migrate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Olá, estou iniciando no php mais o framework Laravel, e minha duvida é quanto ao comando 
`php artisan migrate`
 para migrar uma tabela no banco.

Quando eu executei o comando pela primeira vez ele apresentou esta mensagem `Nothing to migrate` depois de algumas tentativas mais, fechando e abrindo o prompt de comando ele funcionou.

Para não haver duvidas apaguei a tabela e executei o comando novamente, e a mensagem torna a aparecer.
Pesquisei em vários locais e muitos diziam que devia tirar este parâmetro
`--path=app/foo/migrations/2014_01_21_143531_create_teams_table.php`(exemplo)
que usei somente para ver se funcionava, ainda assim a mensagem continua a aparecer.
Espero que alguém possa me explicar um pouco mais sobre este comando e o que ocasiona esta mensagem `Nothing to migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

Para recriar todas as tabelas e executar o arquivos de `seed`, basta executar o comando abaixo.

```
php artisan migration:refresh --seed
```

Ele ira fazer o roll back de seu banco e ira recriar o banco.

Documentação: [link](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations);

Answer (score 1):

Quando você executa uma migration no Laravel, todos os registros são gravados (por padrão) na tabela `migrations`. Lá contém as informações de quais migrations foram executadas.

Se você apagar as tabela "na mão", sem limpar essa tabela `migrations` (não recomendado), ele vai reconhecer como se as migrations estivessem sido executadas, mesmo que as tabelas referente à elas não exista.

Como recomendado, você deve utilizar o comando abaixo, para reexecutar toda as migrations.

```
php artisan migration:refresh
```

O problema é que, se você tiver deletado alguma tabela na mão, poderá ter problemas, pois quando você executa o comando acima, ele roda *down* (Rollback) em todas as migrations para depois executar a *up*.